# Session_End() alternatives for SQL Server session state

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session-state

I have an application in MVC4 which has some logic in the `Session_End()` method in `Global.aspx.cs`.

However, I need to change the session state from `InProc` to `SQLServer`, and this means the `Session_End()` method will not get called.

I've tried to effect a [workaround](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21156/ASP-NET-HttpModule-for-handling-session-end-with-S)  but I couldn't get it to work.

What are the alternatives, if any, to `Session_End()`? All I need is the ability to run some logic when the session times out.

Answer (score 1):

The session doesn't time out when `SessionState` is in `SQLServer` mode.

From the [MSDN page on Session-State Modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx):

> **SQLServer** mode stores session state in a SQL Server database. This ensures that session state is preserved if the Web application is restarted and also makes session state available to multiple Web servers in a Web farm.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but if the Session has ended, the Session property will be null or empty?

Perhaps you could test for that, maybe in a BaseController or something which is called for each request.